# Extension Crashing Python on Import?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python extension that is built and installed through distutils (using mingw on windows). However on import of this module the interpreter crashes. Is there anyway to debug and figure out why it crashes?

I did look around online and couldn't find anything specific, or any examples.

*EDIT*

Sorry i am trying to compile for python 2.5.4 (we need 2.5.4, since we use arcgis geoprocessor library):

http://effbot.org/media/downloads/ftpparse-1.1-20021124.zip

On windows, i define crash as: "Python.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close"

I'll try debugging with GDB

*EDIT 2*
For what ever reason, doing a

```
setup.py clean
```

For the package and doing:

```
setup.py install
```

fixed all the problems. :psyduck:

Comment: Define "crash". Is there a stack trace? Segfault? Does the cpu catch fire and open a sulfurous portal to Hell through which demons come to jump into your nose?

Comment: It is only my guess that there are no back traces for you to show and if that is the case then loading the extension might be the cause of the segfault.

Provide details about the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose using gdb see http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/gdb

Answer (score 3):

Simply running the following may give you a clue about what call is causing the issue without having to break out a debugger. But if you just get a silent crash you're going to have to put on your detective hat as per Xavier's answer.

```
strace python -v -c "import faultylib"
```